# UITableView with accessibilityElementsHidden = YES not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, accessibility, voiceover

I have a UITableViewController. I set accessibilityElementsHidden = YES on the tableView. With VoiceOver on, I can no longer swipe between the cells, which is what I'd expect. However, I can still tap on the cells and they get selected and their labels read out loud. How can I make the tableView completely invisible to VoiceOver?

Answer (score 0):

try to set `accessibilityElementsHidden = YES` on the `UITableViewCell` in your

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```